# How to test angular 2 directive Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, testing, directive

I have my directive that I want to test. Every time I run the test, I get an error that says 'Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target'. How do I get the parameters of the constructor into the test?

This is my directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[fbInputlistener]'
})
export class InputlistenerDirective {

  constructor( private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer ) { }

  @HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {
    if(this.elRef.nativeElement.value.length > 0) {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'form__input--has-value', true);
    } else {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'form__input--has-value', false);
     }
  }
}
```

This is it's test:

```
import { InputlistenerDirective } from './inputlistener.directive';

describe('InputlistenerDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new InputlistenerDirective();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I would just host the directive on a dummy mock component, and test it with the full framework using the TestBed.

Comment: @peeskillet Yup that did the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {TestBed, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {Component, DebugElement} from "@angular/core";
import { InputlistenerDirective } from './inputlistener.directive';

@Component({
   template: `<input type="number" fbInputlistener value="12345">` 
})
class TestInputComponent {
}

describe('InputlistenerDirective', () => {
   let component: TestInputComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestInputComponent>;
   let inputEl: DebugElement;


beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [TestInputComponent, InputlistenerDirective]
   });

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestInputComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
});

It('Directive should add class to test input', () => {
   inputEl.triggerEventHandler('keyup', null);
   fixture.detectChanges();

   expect(inputEl.nativeElement.classList.length).toBe(1);
 });
});
```